# Erroneous code acting like a SELECT * Statement

Tags: sqlite

I am teaching myself how to use SQLITE3. I have a COMPANY table that contains the following data: (Thank you TutorialsPoint)

```
ID          NAME                  AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY    
----------  --------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------

1           Paul                  32          California  20000.0   
2           Allen                 25          Texas       15000.0   
3           Teddy                 23          Norway      20000.0   
4           Mark                  25          Rich-Mond   65000.0   
5           David                 27          Texas       85000.0   
6           Kim                   22          South-Hall  45000.0
```

I was trying retrieve all the data from the table where the AGE was 25 or 27. I executed the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE AGE = 25 OR 27;
```

I now realise that the syntax I used was incorrect, but can someone tell me why this erroneous code is returning the equivalent of a `SELECT * FROM COMPANY`?

Thank you, Sean

Comment: Does *or 27* evaluate to *or TRUE* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because your query can be equivalently rewritten as

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE 1=1;
```

(see the last part of the query `WHERE AGE = 25 OR 27;` -- `OR 27` is equivalent to 1=1)

There is no such type as `boolean` in sqlite. Instead, it is stored as an `integer`. So you are saying "Please, give me all companies where (insert any statement that is allways true)".

Comment: Thank you Kostyantyn. That makes sense now.

Comment: @Horkrine OP knows the fix, he wants to know why this mistake leads to this outcome: _**I now realise** that the syntax I used was incorrect, but can **someone tell me why** this erroneous code is returning the equivalent of a SELECT * FROM COMPANY?_